# React Image Selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

so I am trying to use an if statement but don't know how to word it properly, or if I can with React in a jsx file. My goal is to select the image based on the first name attribute I chose and worked so here is the code for the App.js I am trying to keep it as simple and basic as possible so I can try to figure out a nice clean way to do it but I have no clue. Thanks :)

```
import './App.css';

import PersonalCard from './components/personal.jsx'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <PersonalCard firstName="Lou" lastName="Ferrigno" age={68} hairColor="Black" />
        <PersonalCard firstName="Arnold " lastName="Schwarzenegger " age={73} hairColor="Brown" />
        {/* Franco died in 2019 at the age of 78 :'(  */}
        <PersonalCard firstName="Franco" lastName="Columbu " age={79} hairColor="Brown" />
        <PersonalCard firstName="Frank " lastName="Zane " age={78} hairColor="Black" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

now here is the code for the jsx file

```
import React from 'react';


const theW ={
    width:'400px',
}

const PersonCard = props => {

    const {lastName,firstName,age,hairColor} = props
    return(
        <div className="card" style={theW}>
            <img className="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image"></img>
            <section className="card-body">
                <h1 className="card-title">{ lastName }, { firstName }</h1>
                <p className="card-text">Age: { age }</p>
                <p className="card-text">Hair Color: { hairColor }</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
export default PersonCard;
```

Comment: Or is there a way I can put in the jsx file something like <img src='{firstName}.jpg' />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add the src attribute of the image as dynamic.
so in your code

```
div className="card" style={theW}>
            <img className="card-img-top" src={`location/${firstname}.jpg`} alt="Card image"></img>
```

here **location** is the path to the file

**EDIT**
webpack require additional files to be imported so

```
   <img className="card-img-top" src=require({`location/${firstname}.jpg`}) alt="Card image" />
```

Comment: I tried this since I got some rest and it didn't work. I tried location/pic.jpg don't know why it's not working. yes i know src/components/img.jpg just to see if I could get one pic working but to no avail :'(

Comment: So do I have to import them for react like import images from image \\folder?

Comment: ok.webpack may shwoing  this error try to do like <img src=require({`location/${firstname}.jpg`})/>

Comment: also don't need to add additional closing tag for <img> . img is self closing element

Comment: I don't know why it did that </img> LOL I have never used and img tag like that lol

Comment: I also did this import image from './image/pic.jpg'

Comment: is that showing any errors? like cant import module etc.share the error

Comment: So now I imported them all like such import Franco from './image/Franco.jpg' and I tried to make it so that src={firstName} because then that would be equivalent to the name of the image but that didn't work. Maybe I could make an if statement like if (firstName == Franco then use Franco for image but my mind is stuck  lol

Comment: you dont need to import each name for the project just import with require dynamically src=require({`.image/${firstname}.jpg`})

Comment: I tried that and the whole page is red squiggly lines

Comment: src={require(`./image/${firstName}.jpg` )}  now that did something but the images are still not showing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for trying @ Sharun K K but even though it might have been something I was doing wrong that require way did not work for me.
What I did to fix this and shout out to this video on youtube [Esterling Accime](https://youtu.be/taMJct5oeoI)!,was instead I added an image folder in the public section and did this line of code

```
<img className="card-img-top" src={`/images/${firstName}.jpg`} />
```

so that worked wonders for me once again thank you so much for the help :). Another issue with this was I put a name in the App.js file I did this

```
// this is wrong because of the space in the firstName 
<PersonalCard firstName="Lou " lastName="Ferrigno" age={68} hairColor="Black"  />
// so no spaces like this
<PersonalCard firstName="Lou" lastName="Ferrigno" age={68} hairColor="Black"  />
// and all my issues went away.
```